# How do i retrive a post from a custom post type

Tags: posts, post-type

How can i retrive a post from a Post Type were "distributie_seriale" is a relationship field.

Ex:

I add an Actor to PostType - actors ( Add post)

next

I add an Serial on PostType- serial ( Add post)
I link the serial in Relathionship Field with the actor.
After i do that i click Publish.

Results: On the Serial Page i retrive the actor, but the question is... 
How i retrive the serial on Actor Page.

Extra : The movies are in  WP Post's
The code down it retrive me the movies of post's Page.

How can i retrive a post's that is select, from a Post Type , in my case -- serial

```
$movies = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'distributie' AND meta_value LIKE '%".get_the_ID()."%'");
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $movies) );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting movie and serial on actor page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84426/getting-movie-and-serial-on-actor-page)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I completely understand your question, but if you're just looking for an array of movies that are of the type distributie, based on the ID of the current Loop object, this will do it:

```
$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'movies',
'meta_key' => 'distributie',
'meta_value' => get_the_ID()
)
$get_distributie_movies = get_posts( $args );
```

(not tested)

Comment: Christopher Ross thanks for responding, the solution did not work..  please look here.. excuse my duplicate posts...http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84426/getting-movie-and-serial-on-actor-page